# Reading Packed Bytes in Polars

Tags: python-polars

I have a file full of a sequence of raw data. Each struct has a schema (it's qqiffff for python format). I have a list of 7 column names and I want to load this as one row per struct into a polars DataFrame in python.

Sorry if this is well-known, but I wasn't sure how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hit the raw data with a numpy dtype (frombuffer might work) then you can turn it into a beary Dataframe of your choice (pandas or polars)

Comment: How would I convert this to a numpy dtype given that I have that mix of different types in qqiffff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy supports packed compound dtypes, earning it some ire for supporting row major data representation, but it's great for reading data that is already row major.

```
import numpy as np
mydtype=np.dtype([('field1','i8'),('field2','i8'),('field3','i4'),('field4','f4'),...])
mydata=np.fromfile('myfile.file',mydtype)
mydata['field3'] #access data with field name string in brackets
myDataframe =bear.DataFrame()# alternatively make a dictionary and feed it here
for field in mydata.dtype.names:
    myDataframe[field]=mydata[field]
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks good! I would actually say look at this too: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/8620